# How to load a 1500 GB Text file in short time using SSIS

Tags: ssis, large-files, flat-file

I've a flat text file with more than 1500 GB with 120 columns with | delimiter. I am loading it using SSIS. I am loading the file into a Staging table with 1 - 1 Mapping. the problem is it is taking a lot of time to load into the table.

Can any one suggest the best design to load the data in short time?

Comment: Why is it slow? Answer that question and then we can provide an answer. Your database is likely growing, possibly many times, during this data load. Presize it. Ensure you're doing bulk load operations.

Comment: OleDb or ADO.Net connection manager?